# How to insert data from CheckedListBox to database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need to insert data to an Access Database from a checkedlistbox. The items in the checkedlistboxes are foreign keys and are displayed by their names not by their IDs. What I needed to do is when I click the "Add" button, it should insert the items' IDs and their names as string (str) to Services_Availed table in the database but the names won't display even though a new data is inserted ( adds another ServicesAvailed_ID everytime I click the add button).

Here is what I tried:

```
Private Sub btnAddService_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddService.Click
Try
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim str As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    If chcklstbx1.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To i < chcklstbx1.CheckedItems.Count
            If str = "" Then
                str = chcklstbx1.CheckedItems(i).ToString
            Else
                str += "," + chcklstbx1.CheckedItems(i).ToString
            End If
        Next
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\rose&mike\Desktop\DbSysDel3\salondbaccess.accdb"
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert Into Services_Availed(AvailedNames) Values(@ServiceType_Name)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceType_Name", str)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully")
        con.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please select at least one item")
        While (chcklstbx1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            chcklstbx1.SetItemChecked(chcklstbx1.CheckedIndices(0), False)
        End While
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your intention to add a new row for every item that is checked, or jsut add one row for all? Your code will only add one row.  For how to reference names and ID's, take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn yes I wanted to add one row but for every item that's checked, it should be converted to `String` ,separated by a comma, and saved to the *AvailedNames* table. The code does work but there seems to be a problem with the values I'm using as reference. The items in the checkedlistbox are from a table called *Service_Types*. Please point out where I got it wrong.

Comment: In you code for the 'Click' event, you check to see if any items are checked (your first 'IF' statement), then you loop thru all of the checked, but your code to insert a new record is OUTSIDE of that loop, thus it will only be executed once. You should move your 'con.conn..', 'con.open',  just after your 'IF', then move your 'Next' to just before 'con.close'. Did you look at the article on how to reference items?

Comment: I did your suggestion and it won't add another row. I'm still going through the article. Thank you.

Comment: Then update your question with the latest version of the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reduce your FOR statement down to:

```
For i = 0 to chcklstbx1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
```